# DAG zero... Getting clearer information from the Console Window

Tags: command-line

How do I get more detailed information for the following message?
This message appears in the Console Window.

```
DAG zero... not allowed to happen!
```

The goal is to know the cause of this message and correct the situation.

Comment: Could you tell a bit more about the context? What operation were you performing before the error? Which are the steps to reproduce it?

Comment: I do not have a timeline because the file is weeks old and I ignored the message when I first saw it.  I open the console periodically for warnings and to see messages from my scripts.  I am not claiming I know of any negative effects of just continuing to ignore the message.

Comment: I believe the last work was volume rendering with particle point density in Cycles.